# How to get the found array to execute the function in VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, function, find, range

The cell "wi.Row(foundValue.Row).Columns("H")" contains values "T" and "K". Those figures refer to function Examin01 and Examin 02 respectively.If the cell contains a "T" then function "Examine01" is executed.If cell contains both figures "T,K" then both functions should be executed after one another.

My issue is twofold: first, How do I get the macro to jump into the relevant function e.g „Examine01, after the cell value e.g "T" is found. And secondly, how can I get the macro to execute both function one after another if both figures are found in the cell?

```
Sub Examine()

 Dim t As Integer
 Dim Rule as Variant
 Dim RuleArray(1) as Variant

 Set ws = Worksheets("R")
 Set wt = Worksheets("G")
 Set wi = Worksheets("R")

 RuleArray(1)= ("T,K")

 t = 2


 Do
   For Each cell In ws.Range("A" & t)
   Set foundValue = wi.Range("A1:A75").Find(cell.Value)
       If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
           For Each Rule in RuleArray
                   If IsInArray(RuleArray, wi.Row(foundValue.Row).Columns("H"),0)=True
....'the code that makes the array jump into the relevant function??
....


 Funtion IsInArray(ValToBeFound as Variant, arr as Variant) as Boolean
 IsInArray=(UBoound(Filter(arr, ValToBeFound)))
 End Funtion


 Function Exam01(ByVal t as Long, ByVal ws as Worksheet) as Boolean 
 E01 = True
 If ws.Range("B" & t).Value = 0 Then E01 = False
 End If
 End Function


 Function Exam02(ByVal t as Long, ByVal ws as Worksheet) as Boolean 
 E02 = True
 If ws.Range("B" & t).Value > 30 Then E02 = False
 End If
 End Function
```

Comment: For starters, try using the properties of an array. Yours has 2 elements as arrays are zero-based by default. So  `RuleArray(0)= "T" // RuleArray(1)= "K"`

Comment: Hi SJR, when I include the "//" i get an syntax error.

Comment: Sorry those two bits need to be on separate lines without the "//". Then loop through each element of the array and proceed to relevant function for each item. Bit rushed atm so not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Nope, It doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: What doesn't work? If you've tried new code, add it to your question please.

Comment: It does now. I am just wondering whether it is possible to put the value in the cell "wi.Row(foundValue.Row).Columns("H")" which a T into the name of a function e.g. Examine_T= Examine_"wi.Row(foundValue.Row).Columns("H")"